# Joining a pivot table to another table (HABTM join HABTM and model associations)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, cakephp, model

Let's say that I'm building an engine that has many blogs and many users. Users can have many blogs and blogs can have many users (users hasAndBelongsToMany blogs). I would create a pivot table called users_blogs which would look like this:

```
id user_id blog_id role

1  1       1       admin
2  1       2       poster
3  2       2       admin
```

So, user 1 belongs to blogs 1 and 2, and user 2 belongs to blog 2. User 1 is an admin in blog 1, and a poster in blog 2, and user 2 is an admin in blog 2.

There will also be posts. users_blogs will have many posts, and posts can have many users_blogs. They would be joined with a pivot table that would look like this:

```
id users_blog_id post_id
1  2             1
2  3             1
```

So, referring to users_blogs, user 1 on blog 2 collaborated with user 2 on blog 2 to create post 1.

I'm relatively new to MVC, so I'm wondering if A) the "role" data in the first table is where it's supposed to be?, and B) Is there a more correct way to do this structure? Frameworks will do the magic for me, I just want to make sure that this makes sense, and I've got the correct naming conventions. I'm using Cakephp, but I also think that this question could be answered by a Rails programmer.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're on the right track.  If I understand you, this is how it should be:

I didn't completely understand one of your statements, so I'm going on the assumption that a `post` `belongsTo` a single `blog` like most.

First issue is, your "pivot table" naming convention must be in alphabetical order - so it should be `blogs_users`, not `users_blogs`.  Seems minor, but won't work otherwise.

**Associations:**

```
blog hasMany post
post belongsTo blog

user hasAndBelongsToMany blog //allowing more than one user to be associated to a blog
blog hasAndBelongsToMany user

user hasAndBelongsToMany post //allowing more than one user to be associated to a post
post hasAndBelongsToMany user

role hasAndBelongsToMany user //better to keep roles in a table that just a string
user hasAndBelongsToMany role //use 'with'=>'blogs_users' in your association
                              between user/roll
```

**Tables:**

```
users            (id, name, ...etc)
blogs            (id, title, ...etc)
roles            (id, role)
blogs_users      (id, user_id, role_id, blog_id)
posts            (id, title, blog_id)
posts_users      (id, post_id, user_id)
```

**Update:**

I'm not the best at this - still somewhat learning myself, but - off the top of my head, you could get the posts from blog 1 created by user 1 via something like this:

```
$blogId = '1';
$userId = '1';
$posts = $this->Post->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'User.id' => $userId,
        'Blog.id' => $blogId
    )
);
```

Comment: You're right about the alphabetical thing and you answered my first question that "roles" should reside in the pivot table.

Say user 1 has 100 blogs. If we wanted to get user 1's posts from blog #1, we would have to grab all of the posts_users, and then grab all the posts, and then match blog_id and user_id.

Instead, what if we had a blogs_users_posts table. We would grab one record from blogs_users (blog_user_id) which would represent user 1 and blog #1, and find all posts in blogs_users_posts with that blog_user_id. Doing this seems faster than the the way above. Is this right?

Thank you!

Comment: If you want to get user 1's posts from blog #1, we assume you already have the blog id and the user_id - so - just pull any posts from that specific blog (posts table has a blog_id), then set the condition that you only want posts with user_id = 1.  Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: I think I realize where my problem was. I thought that there would be some value in adding blog_id to the users_posts table. If I had the user_id and blog_id in one table, I could find all post_ids from that user in that blog without leaving that table. This would really only be useful for counting the users posts in a blog, maybe other things? If I had both user_id and blog_id in one table, why not combine them to be users_blog_id and refer to users_blogs. This would make the table the same size as users_posts, with more info. I thought that it would save query time, too, but it doesn't.

Comment: Very glad you got it worked out! :)  I understand your logic - it makes sense - and it could work either way I suppose, but I'm always a big fan of keeping data (like which user has which blog) in one place.  Glad to hear it wasn't a performance it doing it this way! :)

Comment: One last question: what post->find expression would you run to get all posts from blog 1 and user 1?

Comment: Added an "off the top of my head" query that I think should work for you.

Comment: This was what I thought as well, but after messing around with it for a long time and trying everything, the only way I could get it to work was with using bindModel to bind Posts to Users, and then running that query.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a rails, cakephp or mvc question but your relational database schema looks as it should based on what you described.

Comment: Cake and Ruby do a lot of "automagic" stuff when the naming conventions are correct. I'm also asking if this way of making these associations is best practice, or is there a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Cakephp, but there are three problems about you join table which will break a habtm relationship in Rails.

1) The join table is named `blogs_users`, by default.
2) The join table must not have any other attributes, such as `role`.
3) The join table must not have an `id`.

So your `blogs_users` table should have only `blog_id` and `user_id`, otherwise you'll get errors.

If you want your join table to be a full fledged model in Rails, you'll want to use a `has_many :through` relationship. So

```
class User
  has_many :user_blogs
  has_many :blogs, :through => :user_blogs
end

class UserBlog
  belongs_to :blog
  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :role, :in => ALLOWED_ROLE_NAMES # Example of logic in this model
end

class Blog
  has_many :user_blogs
  has_many :users, :through => :user_blogs
end
```

Comment: He mentioned he's using CakePHP, therefore, #2) is incorrect, and #3) is also incorrect

Comment: I heard that Cakephp was very very similar to Rails. If it's true that Rails doesn't let you do this, and CakePHP does, then this question isn't appropriate for a Rails answer. Sorry about that.